# What's a reliable way to lazy-load background images declared in CSS (not inline)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

There are a few jQuery plugins and even WordPress plugins that are ready to use out-of-the-box, but I couldn't find any that can handle background images set by an external CSS file or a  block.

Is there something that works in these situations?

Comment: Wouldn't pre-loading them work for your situation? If so here is a thread that provides plenty of good options. We used pre-loading at my previous gig and it worked great for our use case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476679/preloading-images-with-jquery

Comment: Since the browser is matching the CSS rule and loading the image, I would suspect you would need to change the classname to something else, and then reset the correct classname whenever you are ready to load the image.